# Bootstrap Tabs + jQuery BBQ

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/CQXBx/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab1">Profile Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab2">Email &amp; Password</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab3">Phone Numbers</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <span>Tab1</span>
        </div> <!-- tab1 -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
            <span>Tab2</span>
        </div> <!-- tab2 -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab3">
            <span>Tab3</span>
        </div> <!-- tab3 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabs = $('.tabbable'),
    tab_a_selector = '.nav-tabs a';

    tabs.find( tab_a_selector ).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        var state = {},
        // Get the id of this tab widget.
        id = $(this).closest('.tabbable').attr('id'),
        // Get the index of this tab.
        idx = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;
        // Set the state!
        state[id] = idx;
        $.bbq.pushState(state);
    });

    $(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
        tabs.each(function () {
            var idx = $.bbq.getState(this.id, true) || 0;
            $(this).find(tab_a_selector).eq(idx).triggerHandler('click');
        });
    })

    .trigger('hashchange');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body { background: #fff; }
```

I can't seem to get the Bootstrap Tabbable (tabs-left) to work correctly with BBQ's hashchange.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/CQXBx/4/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample, I believe the problem is in here:

```
tabs.find( tab_a_selector ).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).tab('show');
  var state = {},
  // Get the id of this tab widget.
  id = $(this).closest('.tabbable').attr('id'),
  // Get the index of this tab.
  idx = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;
  // Set the state!
  state[id] = idx;
  $.bbq.pushState(state);
});
```

In this code block you're trying to get the `id` of the closest element with a `tabbable` class, but the nearest matching element doesn't have an `id` property. You're then passing the empty `id` property into `state` and calling `bbq` with an essentially empty array.

If you put an alert or breakpoint in the middle of that code block you can see the tab actually does change momentarily but then get reset to the first tab because it's at index 0 which is what your `hashchange` event handler defaults to when it can't find a matching `id`.

Comment: Without knowing more about BBQ and what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to say. Your question asked for help where figuring out what you were doing wrong. This should get you started in the right direction.